# Booting iMac from External SSD & UASP support in iMac, Docking station or USB to Sata Adapter?

Tags: macos, imac, usb, ssd, bootable-disk

I have Late 2013 iMac which has 5400 RPM HDD and I find it really slow. So, I purchased a Crucial MX500 SSD. I have now cloned my HDD to SSD using superduper and then booted from it. It worked. But I have run into the following issues:-

1. After some time of inactivity when I return to unlock my iMac and use it. It doesn't work. I need to force shutdown and restart again. Why is this happening? Does power supply to external SSD (connected in USB) get cut off? Do I need a docking station that provides power supply as well or USB 3.0 port provides sufficient continued power to External Bootable SSD?
2. The speeds which I'm getting for both read & write are only about 100MB/s, which is below my expectations. I couldn't find any thunderbolt to SATA III adapter in India. Should I consider using UASP supported SSD enclosure? Does my iMac late 2013 support UASP?

Thanks,